# How to add "exotic" keyboard layouts on Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout

Checking the `load-extra-items` at `org.gnome.libgnomekbd.desktop` (via a.g. [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor) [image: Install dconf-editor]
) should theoretically do the trick. Apparently it was a known bug until a year ago ([Option to enable extra keyboard layout is lost Edit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1009995)).

Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me with some walkaround (I'd like to enable the `Polish (international with accents)` keyboard layout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exotic layouts get enabled with the following invocation of `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [Keytouch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=Keytouch&op=). Look over the default built ins to see if your keyboard is supported. If not you can download the companion editor if you need more flexibility.

Comment: ATM Keytouch doesn't exist on Ubuntu's repositories for Trusty.

Comment: It isn't in Precise either but you can download the Deb  for Keytouch from [Sourceforge](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-keytouch.php).

Comment: Looks promising, but I fear that it may not do stuff "the Ubuntu way", and so might interfere with the system components. I've never tried it, though.

Comment: I used it here on a older Logitech board. The setup and implementation worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Walkaround:

First we need to learn the identifier of the layout we wish to custom-add to the list. For that we need to peek at the appropriate file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. This is two-step procedure:

First we need to find the file that defines the layout we want to apply (e.g. by `grep <phrase> *` launched from terminal in this directory). Name of the file is the name of the `configItem`, that we will need later. It will be `pl` in my case.

Then we open this file in editor and find the beginning of the block defining our desired layout. It has a form like `xkb_symbols "intl" {`, where `intl` is the identifier of the layout.

Knowing it, we need to `gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, and find the beginning of the `configItem` item. In it there will be a list of already defined layuts (`variants`). We need to insert our own, using one of the existing ones as a template; it would be

```
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>intl</name>
        <description>Polish (international with dead keys)</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
```

in my example.

Although the name of the layout will be available in the Ubuntu's settings manager immediately, we need to reboot (or maybe: logout, login?) for the new layout to really start working.

---

By the way, the described layout looks promising for power users, and it is available with "latin" variant, which is compatible with other languages then Polish. It is 100% compatible with already-present engravings on most keyboards, and features funny and easy to remember layout for extra commonly used symbols. See the whole rationale [in this PDF](http://marcinwolinski.pl/keyboard/rational_keyboard.pdf).